# Unable to ignore files in Visual Studio 2012 using .tfignore file

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm having some problems ignoring files in VS 2012 and was wondering if anyone could help. Essentially what I'm trying to do is ignore the Web.config file from a project in a solution.

I'm aware of the ability to "Exclude" the file but I wanted something a little more robust as I really don't like the way that VS re-includes the files when I right click the solution file and click "Check In".

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Made a change to the Web.config
2. Team Explorer tab->Excluded Changes->click "Detected" link
3. Right click a file->"Ignore this local item" to create .tfignore file*
4. Open the .tfignore file and append "*.config". Saved.
5. Reopened VS
6. Opened Team Explorer tab again->Pending Changes
7. Web.config still appears in the "Included Changes" list!

   - As explained on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454(v=vs.110).aspx#tfignore

Visual Studio seems to just completely ignore my .tfignore file. 
Does anyone have any ideas/workarounds? Cheers.

Comment: You're trying to reinvent the bicycle. Just run a batch file to add stored away .config file when you need it. Why jumping hoops?

Comment: At what level of the solution is the .tfignore file located?

Comment: Can you paste the content of your .tfignore file here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure you are using a local workspace (can be configured in the advanced part of edit workspace). The .tfignore file should apply as long as it is in your workspace. It will apply recursively to any subfolders and can be overridden by another .tfignore in any of the subfolders. Here's the reference for the .tfignore :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore